Add search results to one or more options
I am running into the following problem. Our company has a search page where we can add results to items managed on another page. Now I am looking for a way to make sure it is clear how and to which items they can add the search results. Things I have come up with at the moment:

Open a drawer to make the selection with an apply button.
Select with dropdown with all the options they can be added to.

Both ways don't really feel intuitive yet. So I am looking for an option to select and/or make clear to what items (on the other) page you can add the search results to.
Thanks in forward!

Please share some wireframes.

To make it clear you could try

Using a tab bar for grouping

Placing a small bar above or below the search results, to see and select the destination.
The tab bar stays visible during action


Contexual overlay via buttons

Placing an add-to button beside each search result opening a contextual overlay displaying the selection process to move the results


Pop-up confirmation

Placing an add button next to the search result once pressed displays a small popup asking where the item will go. The popup could offer options like adding to a selected group or choosing a list if there are multiple alternatives.



